# How I can make reusable coroutines?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, kotlin-coroutines

I'd like to learn more about kotlin, so I've decided to make this post. I'm not sure what should I do with my project at the moment.

Scenario is simple - we have some api call, we have `SwipeRefreshLayout`, and `LAZY coroutine`.

Let's say, that we started `LAZY coroutine` which is responsible for triggering the api call in `ViewModel`, and observing the response as `MutableLiveData`. Now, if user will refreshLayout, and after some actions, there will be need to perform another api call, is it considered good approach to use a `Job` for it?

Asaik, the `coroutines` can't be re-used, but I was able to re-run that specific `Job`.

Example:

```
    private val someJob: Job
    get() = viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch(start = CoroutineStart.LAZY) {
        someViewModel.performApiCall()
        someViewModel.responseMLD.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { someObj ->
            when (someObj ) {
                is wrapper.Success -> {
                    //todo...
                }

                is wrapper.Error -> {
                    Log.e(
                        TAG,
                        "something went wrong"
                    )
                }
            }
        })
    }

....

myBind.refreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener {
    defaultViewsSetup()
    myBind.refreshLayout.isRefreshing = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your property has a custom getter. This means that the code in the getter is executed again every time the property is accessed, and it is instantiating a new lazy coroutine each time. That explains why you were supposedly able to rerun it. You weren't rerunning it. You were generating a new coroutine and running that.

This is quite a clumsy design. It violates the *least astonishment* principle of programming, because we do not normally expect a `val` property to generate new instances as a side effect of accessing them.

If you want to create a new coroutine each time, it should probably be changed to a standard function instead of a property, to match conventions.

But in practice, it seems kind of clumsy to be passing around lazy coroutines in the first place. Lazy coroutines are extremely rare in practice. The only sensible use case I've seen is for creating some kind of a sequential job queue.

There is no way to reuse coroutines. If there's a coroutine design you want to reuse, create it in a function and you can call that function repeatedly.

The more conventional version of your above code would be:

```
private suspend fun someFunction() {
    someViewModel.performApiCall()
    someViewModel.responseMLD.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { someObj ->
        when (someObj ) {
            is wrapper.Success -> {
                //todo...
            }

            is wrapper.Error -> {
                Log.e(
                    TAG,
                    "something went wrong"
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

//....

someListener {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        someFunction()
        someOtherAction()
    }
}
```

Actually, it's a bit odd that you call a suspend function and then listen for the result in a LiveData. Part of the point of coroutines is to get rid of callbacks. Why not directly return the result from that suspend function?